# How to only expose one specific fortran library function to python interface with f2py?

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I have a huge old fortran77 code that I need to call from python using f2py. In fact, I only need to be able to call one function, to simplify, let's call it `run(n)`. So, basically, I need python to be able to pass one integer to one function. Inside, it will generate lots of stuff and call many other routines. As far as I understand, Python doesn't need to know about them. But if I run f2py, it tries to parse through the whole library, choking on spaces in names and some types in the process. The f2py documentation does have an option `[[ only: <fortran functions>  : ]` , but I was not able to figure out how to actually make it work. Could someone please provide an example command to only have f2py create the interface to `run` if that's actually possible?

Comment: Can't you just move `run()` to a different file?

Comment: Oh, ok, thank you, I'm dumb (probably got damaged from looking at one huge f77 file for too long), making a separate file should work for creating the .pyf file. In fact, I have just realized that it's not that long to even create .pyf file manually (the real problem is harder than the dummy example, but still doable). Still kind of wonder if the "proper" command exists.